# NOSQL Injection test on Node.js/Mongoose API

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nosql-injection

I'm diving into NoSql injection so I'm trying to hack my db with postman to see if there is any vulnerability. My requests use parameters to query fields as:

```js
User.find({
    // name: req.params.name
    name: req.query.name
},
function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Mongoose findUsers name error: ', err);
        res.status(505).send({ error: "Internal error." });
        return;
    }
    if (result != null) {
        console.log("Mongoose findUsers name: ", result);
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Found users :",
            data: result
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Mongoose findUsers name: No user found");
        res.status(404).send({
            message: "No user found."
        });
    }
});
```

So I'm trying to pass a name parameter as `{"$ne": null}` or `{"$gt": ""}` , so the query will be `localhost:5000/api/users?name={"$ne": null}`. Though the response I get from the `findOne` method is not null, it will return an empty array. Does than mean that I'm already protected against NoSql injections and not need to sanitize queries parameters or am I just not using the right value to perform an injection? What other test could I run to try and check properly if nosql injection are possible ?
As always many thanks for your help.
Cheers.

Comment: What query parser do you use? I believe the `query.name` is just a string unless your query parser parses it as an object. So `User.find({ name: "{\"$ne\": null }" })` is pretty safe.

Comment: @aleksxor Yes as I don't use any parser, query parameters will always be  strings..so the injection fails. As I always get my query parameters this way, and never parse a json object Is it safe to assume I'm pretty much covered or there are other forms of injection that still could succeed ? again many thanks.

Comment: Did you try `localhost:5000/api/users?name{"$ne"}=null` or `localhost:5000/api/users?name["$ne"]=null` (with or without single/double quotes)? This may let to `name: {"$ne": null}`